# Start Blockchain

Tags: blockchain, genesis

Im looking for a tutorial or link in order to start a customized public blockchain and its coin with POS consensus from zero (not fork)

Thanks for your help

Comment: from zero? Then your blockchain will be finished in 20 years since the size of ethereum source base is about 200,000 lines, and typically a software developer produces about 25 code lines per day, this will take you about 8,000 days to finish your project

Comment: No one can do that alone

Comment: I mean from block zero not code line ... i just want edit some line of code

Comment: Ethereum hasn't completed its switch to PoS yet. You should take a look at other blockchains that already use PoS consensus.